# Java application jars throwing error in Unix environment

Tags: java, unix

We have used maven to package our Java application.
We have a thin `app.jar` file with the application code and configuration, and a `lib` folder with all the dependency jars.
On windows, it all runs fine.

I have copied the files to unix, and added all file permissions to every jar.
When run, the application throws this error from one of the jars in the lib folder:

```
./lib/activemq-broker-5.9.0.jar: line 1: PK: command not found
./lib/activemq-broker-5.9.0.jar: line 2: NC: command not found
./lib/activemq-broker-5.9.0.jar: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
./lib/activemq-broker-5.9.0.jar: line 3: ½NCYzò   Ó¯META-INF/MANIF
```

On unix, this is the format of the command line:

```
java -cp app.jar;./lib/*; com.company.app.Start --param=value1 --param2=value1
```

I wonder if anyone see any obvious issues.

Thanks

Comment: how did you copied? FTP i assume?

Comment: Are you using compatible JVM on both hosts? Is your application code including any java code in strange encodings?

Comment: @rmertins: unix tried to execute the jars, because they are after a comma and that is a command delimiter. I think the system tries it using `sh`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `:` as delimiter in classpath in unix evironment:

```
java -cp app.jar:./lib/* com.company.app.Start --param=value1 --param2=value1
```

Because `;` is a command delimiter.